# How to view the content of a Xamarin.* library referenced in a project

Tags: xamarin.android

In VS2019 I want to browse the classes contained in a library included in my project, for example Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils but instead, when double clicking the package, I get the following error message: 
*"This project cannot be viewed in the object browser because it is unavailable or not yet built. ..."* 
Is there any other way to browse its content?

[image: Error message when trying to browse a Xamarin.* package content from the Solution Explorer.]

Edit: After read the answer of Leo Zhu, I realized that the content of each library can be found in the object browser (as in the following screenshot)
[image: Xamarin.* packages content can be found manually in the Object browser]
I accept it as a workaround, but it would be better if one can call the Object Browser by right clicking the package, as usual with other libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do like this

click tab **View** -> **Object Browser**,then you could see the libraries referenced.

you could quickly find the library you want to read by typing keywords in search

Comment: This is by manually opening the object browser and searching for one of the packages I'm seeing in the project's references. It works as a workaround but, why the object browser option is not available in the context menu by right clicking on, for example, Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging?

Comment: @Lupa yes,this is only way i could find,and it seems only system libs could view by right click.Unless you copy the entire nuget package as a local file and reference it